# Maven build on custom Nifi processor fails on test, java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, unit-testing, apache-nifi

We have been using a custom made set of processors for Nifi and they have compiled fine when using command `mvn clean install`. However, we are currently trying to refactor the code so that a collection of static functions, as well as other repeated code, are all moved to single base class which our processors inherit.

This base class (Let's call it BaseProcessor) inherits the AbstractProcessor class and implements majority of it. Our other processors then inherit this BaseProcessor and add their own codes to it, before calling the base class functions as needed (For example, getting JWT token and making GET/PUT/POST requests).

After refactoring was done, Eclipse and Maven both reported no issues within the processosor codes. However, when we run `mvn clean install`, we receive two failed tests. These tests were never actually used and are just empty classes. Below is sample of such "test". We have two of these, both being the same except their names and classes they refer to being different.

```
package com.company.processors.project;

import org.apache.nifi.util.TestRunner;
import org.apache.nifi.util.TestRunners;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;


public class OurRefractoredClassTest
{

  private TestRunner testRunner;

  @Before
  public void init( )
  {
    testRunner = TestRunners.newTestRunner( OurRefractoredClass.class );
  }

  @Test
  public void testProcessor( )
  {

  }

}
```

However, when we run maven to build our processors, we get following message:

```
[ERROR] Errors:
[ERROR]   FetchJobFromServerTest.init:17 » Runtime java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
[ERROR]   PushUpdateToServerTest.init:14 » Runtime java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
[INFO]
[ERROR] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary for econia 1.3:
[INFO]
[INFO] company............................................. SUCCESS [  3.781 s]
[INFO] nifi-esp-processors ................................ FAILURE [ 10.024 s]
[INFO] nifi-esp-nar ....................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  17.711 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-12-19T11:25:56+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.20.1:test (default-test) on project nifi-esp-processors: There are test failures.
```

Both of the errors on top refer to creation of the test runner. Commenting out this section also causes error. So far, only fix we have been able to found is to simply delete both files. However, this is not ideal, as we want to later implement unit tests.

Anyone have any idea why this is happening? Is this related to refractoring our processors inheriting the new base processor?

Finally, we did not list our base processor in the org,apache.nifi.processors.Processor file, since we didn't want it to be visible to Nifi workflow designers.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that not listing the processor in the `META-INF/resources/org.apache.nifi.processors.Processor` file causes TestRunner to not be able to load the class via reflection / ServiceLoader, so you can try adding that to see if it works (not that it is ideal for your use case). Alternatively you can try instantiating the processor manually, and using one of the other overloaded versions of `TestRunners.newTestRunner()` that takes the Processor implementation rather than just its class name.